# How to convert a 'div' into a dropdown using CSS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a set of buttons encapsulated in a `div` that i want to look like a dropdown:

```
<div id="group">
     <label>Group:</label>
     <div value="1hour">1h</div>
     <div value="2hour">2h</div>
     <div value="3hour">3h</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to convert the above into:

```
<label>Group</label>
 <select>
  <option value="1hour">1h</option>
   <option value="2hour">2h</option>
   <option value="3hour">3h</option>
</select>
```

However while i change the look of the above `div` menu, i'm trying to retain the js code and have the code work exactly the same as before after the change in the look..

```
    $("div#group").each(function(i, ele) {
        $(ele).bind("click", function() { 
            drawChart(this); 
        });
    });


    drawChart: function(){
       //does something here;
    }
```

Is there any way in CSS i change the feel but not the existing code for the div? any ideas??
Thanks!!

Comment: What is your situation where you can't update the html and or js?

Comment: I'll have to make changes at several places in html and js if i change the structure of div..i actually tried changing the event call: $("select").bind("change", function(event) { drawChart(this); });
        });  but didnt work!!

Comment: You could actually do that with JS, but why not change the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use a real select box. You could change the js from a click handler to a change handler like below, and the javascript should behave the same as what you have now, except it will pass the `<option>` element instead of a `<div>` element as a parameter to `drawChart`. Would that work for you?

```
<label>Group</label>
<select>
  <option value="1hour">1h</option>
  <option value="2hour">2h</option>
  <option value="3hour">3h</option>
</select>

$("select").change(function() {
    drawChart($(this).find("option:selected").get(0));
});

drawChart: function(){
   //does something here;
}
```

Comment: "There's no way to get the <div> to behave like a <select> using just css, as you would need click handlers to show and hide the child divs," This is not true, you can css `:active` to respond to click

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know, I still think changing the js is a better fix than trying to mimic the style and functionality of the standard select box

Comment: @SethMcClaine Why would you use `:active` on a div to behave like a `select` tag?  That doesn't even make sense?  Are you suppose to hold down the mouse while selecting an option?  And what if you aren't using a mouse?  Touch?

Comment: Touch will actually hold active until you touch something else... I was just correcting the statement.. not saying the suggestion wouldnt work